# Why can't I open a *.w file in the appBuilder?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a *.w file, referring to two include files (`{incl\include_file.i}`, `{incl\do_something_file.i}`). That first include-file contains the definition of a RECID variable "recordid":

```
  DEF INPUT-OUTPUT PARAMETER recordid      AS RECID.
```

I am capable to compile the *.w file, the listing file looks as follows: (just a fragment)

```
Prompt>findstr "recordid do_something" listing.txt
...
 1    x       DEF INPUT-OUTPUT PARAMETER recordid      AS RECID.
...
 1    x   1   {incl\do_something_file.i
 2    x   1 INPUT-OUTPUT recordid
```

So, the compilation works. In top of that, I've checked the pairs of "&ANALYZE-SUSPEND" and "&ANALYZE-RESUME" clauses and everything is fine.

Nevertheless, I can't open the *.w file, as the mentioned RECID seems not to be known (errors 201 and 196).

**Edit after first comments**
This the exact error message I get while opening the *.w file, using the AppBuilder (I'm working with a Dutch version of the tool, hence the Dutch words in between):

```
---------------------------
Fout
---------------------------
This file cannot be analyzed  by the AppBuilder. 
Please check these problems in your file or environment: 

** Onbekende veld- of variabelenaam - recordid. (201)
** .\incl\<do_something_file>.i Compilatiefout op regel 7. (196)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

**Edit with more information on ANALYZE- clauses**
I've launched following `findstr` command on my code with the following results:

```
Prompt>findstr /I "ANALYZE-RESUME ANALYZE-SUSPEND" <filename>.w
&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _VERSION-NUMBER ... GUI
&ANALYZE-RESUME
&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-CODE-BLOCK _CUSTOM _DEFINITIONS ...
&ANALYZE-RESUME
...
```

I confirm that the number of `&ANALYZE-SUSPEND` clauses equals the number of `&ANALYZE-RESUME` clauses, they are in the right sequence (first a `SUSPEND` and then a `RESUME`) and none of them is commented out.

Does anybody have an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: ``open`` with what? an editor? Or do you mean that you are starting the .w? Also provide the exact error that is reported. You may also want to ``preprocess`` the file, this applies all includes and other preprocess rules. You may also want to look up the ``keyword forget list`` - https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P6962

Comment: Are you sure the error is on that line? And with "open" do you really mean run?

Comment: @StefanDrissen: I've updated the question, based on your comment.

Comment: What is there in  <do_something_file>.i at line 7?
Can you post the content of the file?

Comment: At line 7, there is `other-recordid = recordid`. This might make you believe that this variable (`recordid`) is not yet known, but if this were the case, the file would not compile, which it does (as proven in the debug listing).

Comment: For your information, this is a *.w file, started in the AppBuilder, but I have done modifications on that file outside of the AppBuilder.

Comment: @StefanDrissen: just an idea: in my answer I've written down some advises on how to handle such a situation. Do you agree with them and could we use this Stackoverflow post to list a group of advises in order to handle such a case in general?

Comment: @Dominique I believe it is not a good idea to modify .w file outside of the AppBuilder or PDSOE. Is there something missing in these tools that made you use other editors to modify .w file?

Comment: @austin: my version of the appBuilder has no syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by an include, being outside of an `suspend` `resume` clause, in order to solve such a situation the following command might be useful:

```
findstr /I "ANALYZE {incl" <source_file>.w
```

The result should look like the following:

```
...
&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-CODE-BLOCK _CONTROL C-Win
&ANALYZE-RESUME
&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-CODE-BLOCK _CUSTOM _MAIN-BLOCK C-Win
{incl\something.i}
{incl\something_else.i}
&ANALYZE-RESUME
...
```

You see following rules:

1. The number of suspends and resumes must be equal.
2. Every suspend is to be closed by a resume.
3. Not one of those can be commented out.
4. It is advised to have includes between the suspend and the resume.

Comment: Did you find these rules in documentation or did you construct them based on your findings. If you want to test if your code opens in the appbuilder the only reliable way I found is actually opening in the appbuilder. Opening in appbuilder can be automated if you need that.

Comment: I have created these rules, based on my findings. I'm regularly opening my code in another editor (Notepad++) as the procedure editor only shows parts of the code and there's no syntax highlighting.